# Neo4j C# vertex creation performance

Tags: neo4j, neo4jclient

I am attempting to create 1,000,000 (trivial) vertices on Neo4j using C#. (Community Edition 2.3.2.) Performance is very poor - it takes over 900 s to complete creating those nodes. Am I doing something inefficiently? Why does it take so long?

```
        var client = new GraphClient(new Uri("http://localhost:7474/db/data"), 
            "neo4j", "password");
        client.Connect();

        DateTime t = DateTime.Now;
        Debug.WriteLine(t);

        for (int j = 0; j < 100; j++ ) {
            using (var scope = new TransactionScope(
                TransactionScopeOption.Required,
                new TransactionOptions {IsolationLevel = IsolationLevel.ReadCommitted}
                ))
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
                    var index = new Category { label = i.ToString() };
                            client.Cypher
                                .Create("(class:testItem {index})")
                                .WithParam("index", index)
                                .ExecuteWithoutResults();
                }
                scope.Complete();
            }
            Debug.WriteLine(j);
        }

        Debug.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.Subtract(t).Seconds);
```

---

```
public class Category
{
    public String label { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: How many sec, just create 1,000,000 category, without insert to DB?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Building on Michael's answer - the code you'd be looking at would be:

```
var client = new GraphClient(new Uri("http://localhost:7474/db/data"));
client.Connect();

var data = new List<Category>();
for (int i = 0; i < 20000; i++)
    data.Add(new Category { Label = i.ToString()});

DateTime t = DateTime.Now;
Debug.WriteLine(t);

for (int j = 0; j < 50; j++)
{
    client.Cypher
        .Unwind(data, "item")
        .Create("(:testItem { Label : item.Label })")
        .ExecuteWithoutResults();

    Debug.Write($"{j},");
}
Debug.WriteLine();
Debug.WriteLine($"Took {DateTime.Now.Subtract(t).Seconds} seconds");
```

This creates 100,000 nodes in ~21 seconds, when I tried with 10,000 nodes repeated 100 times, it took 24 seconds, so playing around with the batch size might give different performance, I tried with the full 1,000,000 in one go - that took about ~26 seconds. Either way - a lot better than 900+ seconds!

Comment: You just leave the category allocation.

Answer (score 0):

According to Chris Skardon those create-requests are not batched into few http requests but each of them sends a separate request (not sure if they share all one tx).

It is more efficient to batch them e.g. put 10-50k values into a list and send it as "data" parameter to a cypher statement like this:

```
UNWIND {data} as value CREATE (:TestItem {index: value});
```

or if you have multiple properties create a list of dictionaries as param

```
UNWIND {data} as row CREATE (:TestItem {index: row.index, foo: row.foo, bar: row.bar});
```

for merge operations you can do:

```
UNWIND {data} as row MERGE (t:TestItem {index: row.index}) ON CREATE SET  t.foo=row.foo, t.bar = row.bar;
```

or even

```
UNWIND {data} as row MERGE (t:TestItem {index: row.index}) ON CREATE SET  t += row;
```

or

```
UNWIND {data} as row MERGE (t:TestItem {index: row.index}) ON CREATE SET  t += row.props;
```